# ffmpeg - add logo upper right and extra info on the bottom of an image

Tags: ffmpeg

Today I'm using the following for video and works well:

ffmpeg  -i uploads/input.mp4 -i ./assets/logo.png -i ./assets/telefon.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w='iw*1/5':h='ow/mdar'[v1];[2][0]scale2ref=w='iw*9/10':h='ow/mdar'[v2];[0][v1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:5[vid];[vid][v2]overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10"  uploads/output.mp4

How can I use ffmpeg to obtain the same result having an image as input and a single image as output?

I tried to use output%0d.png but I get 3 images: 1 original image, 1 with logo and 1 with logo and bottom info.